# Анимация кнопки работает, но не переходит на новую Activity

Tags: android

Установил анимацию нажатия на кнопку в *Android sudio*.
Добавил `anim_alpha.xml` в *res-anim*, а также в `Oncreate` *MainActivity* добавил следующий код:

```
       final Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_alpha);
    Button btnalpha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_avto);
    btnalpha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(animAlpha);
        }});
```

В *MainAvtivity* также есть ссылка на переход:

```
public void gotoNewActivityavto (View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
    startActivity (intent);
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы анимация переходила на другую страницу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш метод со стартом новой активности не вызывается внутри обработчика нажатия по кнопке. Однако если просто переместить вызов старта новой активности в метод-обработчик нажатия на кнопку, то активити запуститься быстрее, чем закончиться анимация. Необходимо сделать так:

```
final Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_alpha);
Button btnalpha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_avto);
btnalpha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.startAnimation(animAlpha);
        gotoNewActivityavto()

    }});
```

Метод `gotoNewActivityavto()` надо переписать так:

```
public void gotoNewActivityavto (){
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

Вместо 300 можете поставить свое значение в милисекундах. Это значение овтечает за то, через какое время выполниться метод `run()`

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное! Благодаря таким отзывчивым людям, как Вы, такие, как я, могут понять свои ошибки в начинаниях и научиться чему-нибудь новому!

Answer (score 0):

Метод снизу почему-то не вызывается. Видимо вы забыли прописать его в onclick поле кнопки. Но есть вариант гораздо лучше:

```
   Button btnalpha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_avto);
   btnalpha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_alpha);
        v.startAnimation(animAlpha);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
        startActivity (intent);
    }});
```

Comment: к сожалению, Ваш способ не работает. Выдает ошибку: "cannot resolve  construktor intent". Возможно ли, что в самой анимации установлены параметры, которые задерживают переход? OnClick прописал.

Comment: На какой строчке ошибка? Что за construktor?

Comment: `new Intent(MainActivity.this, TwoActivity.class)`

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, эту нужно поместить сюда? public void gotoNewActivityavto (View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
    startActivity (intent);
}

Comment: @danpetruk, возможно, я неправильно ввожу что-то. Куда именно следует добавить Ваш код и необходимо ли мне удалять часть своего?

Comment: @user186295, Кажется я не совсем понимаю вопрос. Как анимация может переходить на другую страницу, если она прикреплена к кнопке?

Comment: @danpetruk, анимация прикреплена к кнопке, это да. Замысел был такой: пользователь нажимает на кнопку, происходит анимация, далее сразу же переход на вторую avtivity. но по факту сейчас происходит только анимация. В чем может быть проблема?